# How to do unsigned integer arithmetic in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector of dotted-decimal representation of IP addresses.

```
x<-c("255.0.0.0","0.0.0.1")
```

I want to convert it into integer, sort it and output in hex form.

```
f<-function(b){
  b<-as.integer(b)
  return(b[4L]+b[3L]*256L+b[2L]*256L*256L+b[1L]*256L*256L*256L)
}
x<-sapply(strsplit(x,'.',T),f)
s<-sort.list(x)
x<-as.character(as.hexmode(x[s]))
```

This won't work because ips like 255.0.0.0 cause signed int overflow at b[1L]*256L*256L*256L. If I change b into numeric mode, then as.hexmode stops because some elements can't be converted into integer.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example ?

Comment: c("00000001","FF000000") is the expected output, sorted as an increasing sequence.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(x, "\\."), function(i) paste(as.hexmode(as.integer(i)), collapse = ""))` I think this takes you closer to your goal.

Comment: Yeah, due to the specifics of your problem, you can convert each part of the address separately, as Ronak's solution implies. Probably need to use `format(, width = 2)` to get 2-character elements for the second address